# SUMIF based on multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I want to get the sum of a range, but I want to change how the sum us calculated based on critera.

Say I have a table as follows

```
Name    | Value
DP      | 2
DP + BC | 4
DP      | 4
DP + BC | 6
```

So I want to have it do a sum that if `Name` doesn't have a `+` in it, it calculates as per normal, but if it has a `+` in it, it multiplies that value by 2. Is this possible?

I've already tried `=SUMIFS(I5:I61,J5:J61,"<>+",J5:J61,"*+*")`, but this doesn't let me manipulate what happens if they match. I've seen the `IFS()` function, but unfortunately I only have Office 2010

Answer (score 2):

This should work in office 2010, I have no way of checking; I checked it in office 2016.

It's an array function, which is indicated by the braces around it. You have to select the cell you want to put the function in, paste the function into the fx area at the top of the screen and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Entr</kbd> rather than <kbd>Enter</kbd> in order to indicate to Excel its an array function. Basically this lets you do element-wise calculations as needed here. 
In the formula, the range `A2:A5` corresponds to the `Name` column values, and `B2:B5` to the `Value` column.

```
=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("+",A2:A5))=TRUE,B2:B5*2,B2:B5))
```

It returns the result `26`

If you aren't getting that with this function, then it probably wasn't entered as an array function. If it is properly entered that way it will show up in the function editor window with braces around it, like this:

```
{=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("+",A2:A5))=TRUE,B2:B5*2,B2:B5))}
```